# How to integrate file plugin for ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was trying to develop a windows 10 application for windows 10 mobiles using Ionic 2, I have a scenario for offline data storage, I tried the sqlite plugin but it was in vain and finally my thoughts end up to use "FILES" to store the data using [file plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/) sadly this plugin returns me this JavaScript run time error: **Unable to get property 'applicationDirectory' of undefined or null reference**. Can someone provide me a working example or any suggestions to solve this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is the code snippet that i am working on.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { File } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  fs: string = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    File.checkDir(this.fs, 'mydir').then(_ => console.log('yay')).catch(err => console.log('boooh'));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Is my working code of check dir:-

```
import { File } from 'ionic-native';

var rootPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
var folderName = 'Your Folder';

this.completePath = rootPath + folderName;
this.subFolder = 'Others';

File.checkDir(this.folderPath + '/', this.subFolder).then((bool) => {
  resolve();
}).catch(() => {
File.createDir(this.folderPath + '/', this.subFolder, false).then(() => {
  resolve();
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cordova-file-plugin is not loaded or not properly installed.

You should use ionic's wrapper

"ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file"

You can use Chrome-Developer-Tool to inspect whether the file-plugin has loaded properly or not.